# Dimensional Analysis on Lorentz Transformations

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, dimensional-analysis

I am on the early stages of special relativity, and I was just introduced to the Lorentz transformation. Here we have the transformations between $x,t$ and $x',t'$

\begin{split}
x'&=\frac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \\
t'&=\frac{t-\frac{v}{c^2}x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
\end{split}

Here we know that $[t']=T$ and $[x']=L$, thus when doing dimensional analysis:

\begin{split}
[x']&=\left[\frac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\right] \\
L&=\frac{L-\frac{L}{T}T}{1} = 0\\
L &\not= 0
\end{split}

Likewise

\begin{split}
[t'] &= \left[\frac{t-\frac{v}{c^2}x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\right]\\
T&=\frac{T-\frac{L^2}{T}\frac{T^2}{L^2}}{1} = 0\\
T &\not= 0
\end{split}

Now you may notice that I keep coming to the conclusion that the Lorentz transform is dimensionally inconsistent. I know that I must've made some mistakes either in my calculations or my understanding. So if anyone could elaborate on what I am missing here that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That is why many authors prefer to use $ct$ instead of $t$ as the timelike coordinate - it has dimensions of length.

Comment: For units, $L - L$ means you are subtracting two quantities with units of length. $L - L= L$

Comment: @mmesser314 summarized it
$L-L=L$
and $T-T=T$

Comment: I have the same issue with Susskind's derivation even if I label the vertical axis "ct", I can't complete the derivation without assuming c goes away halfway through the derivation like he does and then comes back later to make everything dimensionally consistent. You notice there are few complete step-by-step derivations on the internet and those that are available happily write x + t = constant or start off with x'=0 and t'=0 already plotted on the spacetime graph. Susskind does mention that spacetime diagrams utilize relativistic units where velocity and the speed of light are dimensionless

Comment: hence c=1 and v=fraction of c, x is measured in light-seconds. and t is measured in seconds. The reason is that it facilitates the derivation. He then goes on to say that both axes can be thought of as being measured in seconds, even though the x axis is in light-seconds and that is why velocity is dimensionless. He concludes that seconds and light-seconds "amount to the same thing".

Comment: In dimensional analasis, $L+L=L-L=L$ and $L/L = 1$ and $L*L = L^2$.

Comment: Your confusion seems to stem entirely from the assumption that zero inches is not a length and zero seconds is not a time interval.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your dimensional analysis wrongly. There are 2 terms on the right hand side: $\gamma x$ and $-\gamma vt$. All you need to do is to show that each of these terms has the same dimensions, [L], as $x'$. *Subtracting the dimensions of one of the terms from that of the other is a pointless exercise, leading to confusion*.